# validate combobox in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written the below code. But it does not show me the alert message when I don't select the other value and click onto the submit button.
I don't want to use `getElementbyId`. I am using the name attribute of the HTML.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>ComboBox Validation</TITLE>

   <script Language="JavaScript">

   function validate()
   {

      if (document.comboForm.technology.value=="0") \
     {
         alert("Please Select Technology");
     }

   }
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<form name="comboForm">
<select name="technology">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Java Server Pages</option>
</select>

  <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="validate();">
</form>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: That isn't a combobox. It is a "Drop down menu". A combobox is a combination of a drop down menu and a text input (hence the name).

Comment: Why don't you want to use IDs? That's the safest, most reliable, fastest way. That owuld be like writing HTML tags in all caps. Oh wait...

Comment: ok..so how to validate the combobox then ??

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
if (document.forms["comboForm"].technology.value == "0")
```

But really, stop avoiding `document.getElementById`.  That's the clearest, easiest way to deal with this:

```
<select id="ddTechnology" name="technology">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Java Server Pages</option>
</select>

if (document.getElementById("ddTechnology").value == "0")
```